# YOLOv5 backbone replacement from Darknet to Resnet-50 shape issues

Tags: python, deep-learning, resnet, yolov5, darknet

i am a researcher and want to change the current backbon of YOLOv5 from darknet to resnet for that I added the these 2 classes in commons.py.
i am getting this shape error after adding Maxpooling2D and Resblock class names in Yolo.py
model summary is printed on screen succesfully after that this error occurs.

````
class Conv(nn.Module):
    # Standard convolution with args(ch_in, ch_out, kernel, stride, padding, groups, dilation, activation)
    default_act = nn.SiLU()  # default activation

    def __init__(self, c1, c2, k=1, s=1, p=None, g=1, d=1, act=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(c1, c2, k, s, autopad(k, p, d), groups=g, dilation=d, bias=False)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(c2)
        self.act = self.default_act if act is True else act if isinstance(act, nn.Module) else nn.Identity()

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.act(self.bn(self.conv(x)))

    def forward_fuse(self, x):
        return self.act(self.conv(x))
class MaxPooling2D(nn.Module):
    # MaxPooling2D layer with args(kernel, stride, padding)
    def __init__(self, k=2, s=2, p=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(k, s, p)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.maxpool(x)

class ResBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, c1, num_repeats):
        super().__init__()
        self.blocks = nn.Sequential(*[
            nn.Identity() if i == 0 else Conv(c1, c1, k=3, s=1, act=True) for i in range(num_repeats)
        ])

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.cat(x, self.blocks(x))

#Backbone
backbone: [
    [-1, 1, "Conv", [64, 6, 2, 2]],  # 0 - Conv1
    [-1, 1, "MaxPooling2D", [3, 2]],   # 1 - MaxPool
    [-1, 3, "ResBlock", [64]],         # 2 - Res2a, Res2b, Res2c
    [-1, 1, "Conv", [128, 3, 2]], # 3 - Conv3
    [-1, 4, "ResBlock", [128]],        # 4 - Res3a, Res3b, Res3c, Res3d
    [-1, 1, "Conv", [256, 3, 2]], # 5 - Conv4
    [-1, 6, "ResBlock", [256]],        # 6 - Res4a, Res4b, Res4c, Res4d, Res4e, Res4f
    [-1, 1, "Conv", [512, 3, 2]], # 7 - Conv5
    [-1, 3, "ResBlock", [512]],        # 8 - Res5a, Res5b, Res5c
    [-1, 1, "SPPF", [1024, 5]]         # 9 - SPPF
    ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 647, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "train.py", line 536, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "train.py", line 130, in train
    model = Model(cfg or ckpt['model'].yaml, ch=3, nc=nc, anchors=hyp.get('anchors')).to(device)  # create
  File "/home/dev/Documents/yolov5/models/yolo.py", line 195, in __init__
    m.stride = torch.tensor([s / x.shape[-2] for x in forward(torch.zeros(1, ch, s, s))])  # forward
  File "/home/dev/Documents/yolov5/models/yolo.py", line 194, in <lambda>
    forward = lambda x: self.forward(x)[0] if isinstance(m, Segment) else self.forward(x)
  File "/home/dev/Documents/yolov5/models/yolo.py", line 209, in forward
    return self._forward_once(x, profile, visualize)  # single-scale inference, train
  File "/home/dev/Documents/yolov5/models/yolo.py", line 121, in _forward_once
    x = m(x)  # run
  File  "/home/dev/Documents/yolov5/models/common.py", line 90, in forward
    return torch.cat(x, self.blocks(x))
  File "/home/dev/Documents/yolov5/models/common.py", line 68, in forward
    return self.act(self.bn(self.conv(x)))
  File "/home/dev/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/yolov5-FT1Hnn5N-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/yolov5-FT1Hnn5N-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 463, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
 RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [8, 8, 3, 3], expected input[1, 32, 13, 13] to have 8 channels, but got 32 channels instead```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am changing the backbone of YOLOv5 from darknet to resent. therefor i added resblock and maxpooling2D functions in the common.py of yolov5. but these functions are giving shape errors as seen in the error

Answer (score 0):

maybe try set stride of MaxPooling2D to 1.

class MaxPooling2D(nn.Module):

def **init**(self, k=2, s=1, p=0):

Comment: tried doing this. got tis error now 

RuntimeError: Given groups=8, weight of size [8, 1, 3, 3], expected input[1, 32, 13, 13] to have 8 channels, but got 32 channels instead

Comment: how about :  nn.Identity() if i == 0 else Conv(32, 32, k=3, s=1, act=True) for i in range(num_repeats) ?

Comment: got this error now: RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 32, 3, 3], expected input[1, 64, 13, 13] to have 32 channels, but got 64 channels instead

Comment: can you share the change of parse_model in yolo.py? and do you try remove the  [-1, 1, "MaxPooling2D", [3, 2]] from backbone before?

Comment: I did not change that function because the error code is taking me to these classes. that I mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

- check the config of your `ResBlock` class and ensure that the number of input channels matches the expected number of channels for the convolutional layer.
- ResBlock class is expecting 64 input channels, but the convolutional layer within the ResBlock is expecting 8 input channels.

```
class ResBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, c1, num_repeats):
        super().__init__()
        self.blocks = nn.Sequential(*[
            nn.Identity() if i == 0 else Conv(c1, c1, k=3, s=1, act=True) for i in range(num_repeats)
        ])
        self.conv = Conv(c1, c1, k=3, s=1, act=True)  # Add this line

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.cat(x, self.blocks(self.conv(x)))  # Modify this line
```

- Add convolutional layer, and in `forward` mmethod pass the input tensor x through the self.conv layer before passing it to self.blocks. ensuring that the input tensor has the correct number of channels expected by the subsequent ResBlock layers.

Comment: got this error now: RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [8, 8, 3, 3], expected input[1, 32, 13, 13] to have 8 channels, but got 32 channels instead

Comment: the issue is with the conv class in common.py of yolov5. the error refers to this function in conv class.
```def forward(self, x):
        return self.act(self.bn(self.conv(x)))```

Comment: This is the same `error` you got in question, I am confused about  your second comment, can you explain bit more, i will look into it.

Comment: Basically i am changing the backbone architecture of Yolov5 from Darknet to Resnet-50. the architecture of Resnet is mentioned in the question. now there are 2 main files that contain implementation of model in Yolov5. these files are located in Yolov5/model/common.py and yolo.py. the file named common.py contains all classes for the implementation of conv, sppf, and other methods. I put my implementation for resblock and maxpooling2d in this file. so while compiling model, it goes to yolo.py, from their resblock class and from there to conv class in common.py file. can you help me out?

Comment: can you share `conv` class  in question ??

Comment: added. kindly check it. Thanks